# Why do people use URLs that start with just // rather than with http:// or https://

Tags: javascript, html

When I download the source of some HTML documents, I found script elements with `src` attributes whose values start with `//`, like this:

```
 <script src="//code.jquery.com/jquery.js"></script>
 <script src="//netdna.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.1.1/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>
```

Those scripts links has not been working. Can anyone please explain to me why people use those URLs that start with `//` rather than with `http://` or `https://`. Like this:

```
<script src="http://code.jquery.com/jquery.js"></script>
<script src="http://netdna.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.1.1/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>
```

Comment: `//` is http or https depend on protocol of the page.

Comment: they are both valid, will work in any http[s] hosted page. If you take a page like that and try to run it locally using file:/// protocol, they will break, but so will a host of other stuff anyway

Answer (score 10, accepted):

> This scripts links has not been working. can anyone please explain me why people use this tags instead of proper tags.

It *is* a proper link: It's a *protocol-relative* link. On an `http:` page, it's `http:`; on an `https:` page, it's `https:`. By making the link protocol-relative, they don't have to worry about mixed-content warnings and other issues loading the script with a different protocol than the page.

If it's not working for you, it's probably because you're viewing a file from your local file system, e.g., `file:///`. As [Jaromanda X pointed out](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/32680646/why-people-using-this-tag-instead-of-proper-http#comment53205778_32680646), *lots* of things are different when you do that, so it's not (for instance) useful to do that if you're trying to do web development (use a local server instead).

More about protocol-relative links on [my anemic little blog](http://blog.niftysnippets.org/2011/01/skipping-protocol.html).